# Return value msfconsole

Tags: ssh, metasploit

I am trying to script a brute-force ssh attack with `msfconsole -x <command>` using a `.sh` and I need to check if the command has been successful or not so I need a return value.

Looking at the docs I wasn't able to find any information about this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `-o` to create a file with the result of the brute force and then you can read the file using Bash.